unable to connect to SQL on my laptop from Azure data factory
I am trying to connect to SQL on my laptop. I managed to create the linked service. But I keep getting the error below:
Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: 'LAPTOP-OV10HEBE\SQLEXPRESS', Database: 'AdventureWorksLT2022', User: 'maia1'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
The system could not find the environment option that was entered

I changed  the authentication from Window mode to sql Server and Window mode still had the same error.

[..] and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. Did you do that as well?

No, I'll check now


To resolve the above error, follow below steps:

Ensure you are using Self-Hosted Integration Runtime  to connect on-premises SQL server.

Make sure outbound traffic over port 1433 will allowed by your network's firewall.

Add the IP address of the self-hosted integration runtime machine to the list of allowed IP addresses.

Ensure you have given correct credentials to create linked service.


It will test successfully after following above steps as shown below:

